# Physics 101- About Force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, potential-energy

I know that force is $F=−∇U$, but isn't it for the forces that's been done by the system itself? Like when i pull up a ball with external force pointing upwards, shouldn't a ball's potential energy increase?
Is it for field forces only?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression $F=-\nabla U$ holds for conservative forces only. When you pull up an object, gravity (a conservative force) is pushing down so it has a negative sign. However, your own force is not conservative. It means that, for fixed path endpoints, it can have any value and you can not assign a potential energy.